# How to get record from table row number between 20 to 30 with jdo query in Apache ISI

Tags: java, jdo, isis

I am trying to get record's from records 20 to 30.

I have return jdo query which look like

```
@javax.jdo.annotations.Queries( {

    @javax.jdo.annotations.Query(
            name="message_getByUsername", language="JDOQL",  
       value="SELECT FROM com.message.pojo.MessagePojo WHERE  to== :username order by SendDate "),


    @javax.jdo.annotations.Query(
            name="message_getByGroup", language="JDOQL",  
       value="SELECT FROM com.message.pojo.MessagePojo WHERE  group== :group order by SendDate ")



})
```

and i am calling query like

```
public List<MessageConversationPojo> retriveInbox(@Named("username")  String username) {
    List<MessageConversationPojo> listOfMessage = allMatches(new QueryDefault<MessageConversationPojo>(
            MessageConversationPojo.class, "message_inbox", "username", retriveUserByUsername(username)));
        if (listOfMessage.size() != 0) {

        return listOfMessage;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now how can i get record from row number 20 to 30.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't yet implemented in the currently released version (core 1.3.0, objectstore-jdo-1.3.0).

HOWEVER, I've just created a ticket [ISIS-579](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ISIS-579) for the enhancement and implemented the change.  To get back records 20 to 30, you would use:

```
QueryDefault<MessageConversationPojo> q = 
       new QueryDefault<MessageConversationPojo>(...).withStart(20).withCount(10);
```

It'll probably be a few months before this gets released, so in the meantime you can [build Isis from source](http://isis.apache.org/contributors/building-isis.html)